# i have receive email by gmail accounts but not receive other accounts like yahoo,hotmail etc in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Code Is:

```
using System.Net.Mail;<br/>
using System.Net;<br/>
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void home_btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
     msg.From = new MailAddress(home_mail.Text);
     msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("ashwanirawat22@gmail.com"));
    //msg.CC.Add ( new MailAddress(txtcc.Text));
    //msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    msg.Body = home_msg.Text;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(home_mail.Text,home_pass.Text);
    label1.Visible = true;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        smtp.Send(msg);
        label1.Text = "Email Send";

    }
    catch
    {
        label1.Text = "Email Failed";
    }
    home_msg.Text = "";
    home_mail.Text = "";
    home_pass.Text = "";
     }
}
```

Html Code is:

```
Message: <asp:TextBox ID="home_msg" Rows="5" Columns="45" TextMode="MultiLine"runat="server">
</asp:TextBox><br/>
From: <asp:TextBox ID="home_mail"  runat="server" Height="30px" Width="380px"></asp:TextBox></div><br />
Password:
<asp:TextBox ID="home_pass"  runat="server" Height="30px" Width="380px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp; <asp:ImageButton ID="home_btn" ImageUrl="~/images/button.png" runat="server" 
Height="30px" Width="75px" onclick="home_btn_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Now my problem is that I have received only gmail accounts mails in my account but other accounts like hotmail,yahoo etc mails I have not recevied.How can receive all acounts mail in my accounts????

Comment: Your question title talks about receiving mail, but your code sample is sending mail. Could you provide more description of what the actual problem here is?

Comment: you are correct,then you can help me about receive mail coding.Please write the code for receive email.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to write a mail client for you, I can help you with any specific coding questions however.

Comment: ok...please refer a link where I understand the code...

Comment: if i sent email from (msg.From = new MailAddress(home_mail.Text)) to my gmail account then i see the mail in my gmailaccount if sender's account in gmail otherwise i can not receive other account mail see in my gmail account.how can i see other account mail receive my gmail account?

Comment: If you are saying what I think you are, then I don't think you will be able to send mail using google's mail servers from any address other than a gmail address. This is quite a common approach on mail servers to stop spam.

Answer (score 1):

In order sent and receive mail's form different providers you have to change the `smtp.Host` Property. For example,

```
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.live.com";
```

To send from yahoo and live respectively...